# Caption with two figures in a single column

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

How can I put two figures in a single column, with a label (say a), b) ) on the
left and in the middle or top of each figure?

I was trying

```
\newcommand{\Inserttwopgf}[6]{%
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \scalebox{#2}{\input{#1}}%
    \\
    \scalebox{#4}{\input{#3}}%
    \label{#5}
    \caption{#6}
\end{figure}
}
```

but I don't know how to put the labels to the left of each figure. Most of the solutions I found put the figures in a row or with a caption for each figure, I just  need a label. I was also thinking in a minipage but I don't understand quite well the positioning.

Comment: `subcaption` package offers all this and has a few examples in the manual.

Comment: I like to use a tabular for this sort of thing.